# Python 3.5 PIP Install pyperclip Error (Windows)

Tags: python, pip, pyperclip

I'm trying to run pip install command to install a package. However, I'm getting an error below.

Any help is appreciated!

```
C:\Python\Python35-32\Scripts>pip install pyperclip
Collecting pyperclip
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyperclip (from versio
ns: )
No matching distribution found for pyperclip
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked fine:

`pip install pyperclip`

make sure you have internet connection or try to update `pip`:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

In case if that didn't work you can download the library manually from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip) and then install it.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting says, that there's no version of `pyperclip` matching your Python installation (Might be declared by the developer).